# map doesn't show using codeigniter with Googlemaps library on serevr but working fine on localhost

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps

I am using Googlemap v3 api library library for showing Google map it's working fine on localhost, but not working on Server.

my controller function

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('Googlemaps');
       $this->googlemaps->initialize();
        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
        $this->load->view('home',$data);

    }
```

and view

```
<html >
<head>
    <?php echo $map['js'];?>
    </head>
<body>
<?php echo $map['html'];?>
</body>
</html>
```

i have added Googlemaps  and Jsmin in apllication/library

[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aueYo.png)

Comment: Check your console for errors and also check you have google map Api key

Comment: there is nothing on console log , but i got error on log i.e 404 Page Not Found: Js/jquery.min.map.

Comment: but, ihave already added js file of Googlemap v3 api library

Comment: @tejawee place `jquery.min.map` file in  folder `js`

Comment: show your website link

Comment: after placing the jquery.min.map file in folder  i got error log (Undefined property: Googlemaps::$http /home/orangeclap/public_html/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php 1118)

Comment: still not showing map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you. You just need to add google map you can use this

Add this in your view page

```
<div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

Change value of lat and lng according to the latitude and longitude of your location(that will get you from google map) ando also you need to add your **API KEY** in the script **key=YOUR_API_KEY** you can generate your API key from following  [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Style
If you are looking for a full width map

```
#map{width: 100%; height:350px;}
```

Add thidsin your style sheet

Comment: thank you sir, but, your code running perfectly on my localhost but not on server, and also my codeigniter code working good on localhost but not on server

Comment: can you post your website link

Comment: sir your code is working fine on  server as well as localhost , but, still i have problem with codeigniter googlemap library which is only working on localhost

Comment: sorry sir but i can't share my website link, for now i able to add google map on my website by using  your script, Thank you

Comment: I haven't used codeigniter google map library yet. It might be mainly because of API Keys. Is there any additional advantage in using codeigniter google map library.

Comment: Customization of google map is possible with above code